# Rvalue references under the hood

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

Consider the `foo` function

```
void foo(X x);
```

with `X` a matrix cass, and the function

```
X foobar();
```

Suppose that I run

```
foo(foobar());
```

What happens with temporary objects in this case *step by step*? My understanding is that

1. `foobar` returns a temporary object, say `Xtemp1`;
2. `foo` copies `Xtemp1` to a temporary object of its own, say `Xtemp2`, and then destroyes `Xtemp1`;
3. `foo` performs calculations on `Xtemp2`.

On the other side, if I overload `foo` as

```
void foo(X& x);
void foo(X&& x);
```

then the picture will be different and, in particular,

1. `foobar` returns the temporary `Xtemp1`;
2. `foo` does not create a new temporary, but acts directly on `Xtemp1` through its reference.

Is this picture correct or, if not, could someone point out and fix my mistakes? Thank you very much.

Comment: The first example won't compile.

Comment: You should fix the first example. It is not valid C++, although it might be accepted by certain compilers with non-standard extensions.

Comment: Due to temporary elision, there are many possible things that can happen.

Comment: @Pubby @juanchopanza I have taken this example from [Rvalue references explained](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_03.html) by Thomas Becker. It mentions also using `foo(x)` for the first example. Do you mean that also this will not compile?

Comment: References are just references. There's no profound difference between lvalue and rvalue references, except gramatically in what they bind to.

Comment: The C++ rule is that (non-const) l-value references can't bind to temporaries. This means that `foo(x)` will compile fine, but `foo(foobar())` is an error. MSVC accepts it, but that is a non-standard extension of that particular compiler.

Comment: In Thomas Becker's example, both `foo` functions are defined as overloads; the rvalue reference overload is selected.  If only the lvalue reference overload were available it wouldn't compile.

Comment: I have edited my post fixing the pointed out issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foo(foobar());
```

1. `foobar`'s return value is a value, so it's a temporary value.
2. <sup>1</sup>This function will move/copy the return value into local storage for a temporary.
3. <sup>1</sup>This function will move/copy the value in the local storage into the parameter for the call to `foo`.
4. The call to `foo` executes.
5. <sup>2</sup>As `foo` returns, it's parameter is destructed.
6. <sup>2</sup>When `foo` returns, the value in local storage is destructed.
7. `foobar`'s return value is destructed.

<sup>1</sup> These moves/copies may be elided by the compiler. This means that these copy/moves don't have to happen (and any compiler worth using will elide them).

<sup>2</sup> If the moves/copies above are elided, then the destruction of their respective variables are naturally unnecessary. Since they don't exist.

> On the other side, if I overload foo as

1. `foobar`'s return value is a value, so it's a temporary value.
2. <sup>1</sup>This function will move/copy the return value into local storage for a temporary.
3. Overload resolution selects `foo(X &&)` to call.
4. An rvalue-reference parameter variable is created and initialized with the local storage value.
5. The call to `foo` executes.
6. As `foo` returns, it's reference parameter is destructed (not the value it references).
7. <sup>2</sup>When `foo` returns, the value in local storage is destructed.
8. `foobar`'s return value is destructed.

Note the key differences here. Step 4 and 6 *cannot* be elided. Therefore, if `X` is a small type like `int`, then the function will have no choice but to create a fairly worthless reference to an integer. References are internally implemented as pointers, so it's not really possible for the compiler to just optimize that away as a register. The local storage must therefore be *on the stack* rather than a register.

So you will be guaranteed of fewer move/copies. But again, any decent compiler will elide them. So the question is, will `X` generally be too large to fit into a register?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In the cases of my interest, `X` is a matrix-class type and the objects can contain many elements. From yours and Angew's answers, I would say that, when elision occurs, then the computational performance should not be much different, but, to be on the safe side, it would be always recommendable to implement rvalue references, right?

Comment: @JackOLantern: No. It would be best to just make *one* function that takes its argument by `const&`. Unless you are trying to *move* from the parameter (or are using perfect forwarding), you should never take a parameter by rvalue reference. Unless the function needs to modify the parameter for the outside world, in which case you need to take the parameter by non-const lvalue reference. And thus your code won't compile (you shouldn't modify temporaries except to move from them).

Comment: So, the very computational best would be using `void foo(const X& x);`, if I do not need `foo` to change `x`, and `X& foobar();` ?

Comment: @JackOLantern Yes and no. Of course `foobar` shouldn't return a reference but a value, like before, it's just `foo` that now takes a const reference (the default parameter type for any non-modifying/non-copying function.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is almost correct. The only difference is that in step 2., the temporary `Xtemp1` is not copied to an arbitrary-named temporary `Xtemp2`, but to the space of the formal parameter `x` (from declaration `foo(X x)`).

Also, it's possible for copy-elision to kick in, which could mean that the return value of `foobar()` is constructed directly in the space of `foo`'s formal parameter `x`, thus no copying would occur. This is allowed by the standard, but not guaranteed.

Your take on the r-value reference case is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much. Concerning the first part of your answer, do you mean that `Xtemp1` is copied to the stack memory space of `foo`? But in this case, if again my understanding is correct, we would have the output of `foobar` present twice (once as temporary `Xtemp1` and one as a "stack" copy) + one copy action, right? Regarding the second option, does it depend on the compiler? Also, the case when copy-elision appears seems to be as effective as when using the rvalue reference. Am I correct?